# Showing a function $f$ is improperly integrable on $[a,b)$ if $\lim\limits_{x\to b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$ and $g$ is improperly intergrable

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f,g$ be locally integrable on $[a,b)$.  Show that if $$\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$$ is finite and that $g$ is improperly integrable then $f$ is improperly integrable.

I'm quite lost as to how to approach this. I think the idea is that; as $x$ gets close to $b$, $f$ and $g$ are in a common ratio and kind of follow each other so if one converges the other must also. I'm having trouble using $$\lim_{x\to b}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$$ in any meaningful way.  Anything to get me started would be helpful.
Thank you in advance for your time. Apologies for formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea here is to show that $\int_a^x f(t)\;dt$ is one-sided Cauchy as $x\to b^-$ and therefore the one-sided limit must exist. We will use both the ratio limit and the improper integrability of $g$ to show this.

By the limit of ratios, for any $\epsilon_1>0$ there exists $\delta_1>0$ so that for $x \in (b-\delta_1,b)$,
$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}-L\right|<\epsilon_1$$
or equivalently:
$$(L-\epsilon_1)g(x) < f(x) < (L+\epsilon_1)g(x) $$

By the Cauchy $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of one-sided limit (the improper integral $\lim_{x\to b^-}\int_a^x g(t)\;dt$): for any $\epsilon_2 > 0$ there exists $\delta_2 > 0$ so that for $x,y \in (b-\delta_2, b)$
$$\left|\int_a^x g(t)\;dt - \int_a^y g(t)\;dt\right|
= \left|\int_y^x g(t)\;dt\right| < \epsilon_2$$

We then show that $f$ satisfies the above $\epsilon-\delta$ definition:
Pick $\epsilon > 0$, let $\epsilon_1 \in (0, L)$ and $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{L+\epsilon_1}$. Pick $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$, then for $x,y \in (b-\delta, b)$,

\begin{align}
(L-\epsilon_1)\underbrace{\int_y^x g(t)\;dt}_{>\;-\epsilon_2} < 
\int_y^x f(t)\;dt < (L+\epsilon_1)\underbrace{\int_y^x g(t)\;dt}_{<\;\epsilon_2}
\end{align}
using the definition, $\epsilon_2 = \frac{\epsilon}{L+\epsilon_1}$:

$$-\epsilon
< -\underbrace{\frac{L-\epsilon_1}{L+\epsilon_1}}_{\in (0,1)} \epsilon
=-(L-\epsilon_1)\epsilon_2
<\int_y^x f(t)\;dt
< (L+\epsilon_1) \epsilon_2 = \epsilon
$$

as this holds if we swap $x$ and $y$, then

$$\left|\int_y^x f(t)\;dt\right|
= \left|\int_a^x f(t)\;dt -\int_a^y f(t)\;dt\right|<\epsilon$$
Hence the one-sided limit exists, i.e.,
$$\lim_{x\to b^-} \int_a^x f(t)\;dt \quad\text{exists.}$$